# Cómo guardar como una sola imagen, imageview + textview encima, en android studio

Tags: android-studio, imagen, android-imageview, textview

Pues bien, ya muchas aplicaciones lo hacen como los conocidos en redes sociales (estados) como en aplicaciones de filtros y edición de imágenes, agradecería mucho que alguien me ilumine cómo es que se hace, fusionar prácticamente un Imageview con un Textview en una sola imagen y poder guardarla así. Alguna librería en especial? o API? Actualmente uso Android Studio, pero si hay otra herramienta que lo facilite os agradecería.
La idea es algo como Phonto entre otras aplicaciones lo hace,pueden ver la imágen abajo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [StackOverflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com), si eres nuevo, realiza el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), también te recomiendo, que visites [¿Cómo Preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para formular de manera correcta las preguntas, para que estas reciban respuesta; ademas de ser útiles para otras personas.

Comment: podrias agregar una imagen de lo que quieres ya que la verdad no te entendi , por favor edite tu pregunta y agrega mas informacion y en lo posibe una imagen

Comment: Gracias por sus sugerencias, espero alguien pueda ayudarme, soy nueva en esto D:

Answer (score 1):

Lo que yo hago, no se si te puede servir, es guardar el `Layout` como imagen. Es decir, supongamos que tenemos un `LinearLayout` (con un Id que llamaremos pepito) que es el que contiene el `ImageView` y el `TextView`. Ahora, lo que hago es declararlos en mi actividad:

**Ejemplo.java:**

```
private LinearLayout contenido;
private ImageView imagen; 
private TextView texto;
```

Ahora en el **onCreate:**

```
contenido = findViewById(R.id.pepito);
imagen = findViewById(R.id.imagen); 
texto = findViewById(R.id.texto);
```

Para guardar la imagen, en este caso, usaré el método **onClick**  en el que ejecutare un método para guardar el **Layout**:

```
        contenido.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                GuardarLayout();
            }
        });
```

El método **GuardarLayout** contiene lo siguiente:

```
private void GuardarLayout() {
    contenido.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);//habilitamos la función del caché
    contenido.buildDrawingCache(); //crea el cache 
    Bitmap bmap = contenido.getDrawingCache(); //obtiene el mapa de bits del caché
    try {
        guardarImagenMedoto(bmap); //este método guarda la imagen en una ruta
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("GuardarLayout", "GuardarLayout: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        contenido.destroyDrawingCache();
    }
 }
```

El método **guardarImagenMetodo**, como ya dije, guarda la imagen en una ruta:

```
private void guardarImagenMedoto(Bitmap bitmap){
    File rutaArchivo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Tu Carpeta/");//creamos un directorio
    if (!rutaArchivo.exists()) { //sino existe, se crea
        File rutaCrear = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Tu Carpeta/");
        rutaCrear.mkdirs();//creamos
    }

    File archivo = new File(rutaArchivo, "tuImagenNombre" + ".jpg"); //crearemos el archivo en la ruta y con un nombre
    if (archivo.exists()) {
        archivo.delete();//si este archivo existe, con ese nombre, lo reemplazará
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(archivo);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);//creamos la imagen en formato jpg, con la calidad 100
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "¡Se ha guardado con éxito tu imagen!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("guardarImageb", "try: " + "\nRuta: " + rutaArchivo + "\nArchivo: " + archivo); //a traves del logd voy controlando si se crea o no el archivo viéndolo desde el logcat
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "¡Ha ocurrido un error al intentar guardar tu imagen!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("guardarImagen", "Catch: " + e.getMessage() + "\nRuta: " + rutaArchivo + "\nArchivo: " + archivo);
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

si entiendo bien tu pregunta, el objetivo es superponer un texto sobre la imagen. Podrías intentar hacer un `FrameLayout` o un `RelativeLayout`. Yo te recomiendo el primero porque está pensando para soportar ese tipo de acciones.

Te escribo un ejemplo para que te sirva de guía:

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="200dp"/>


    <TextView 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Texto Texto" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Saludos. Espero te sirva.

Comment: He intentado esa forma, y se me ocurre guardar el layout como imagen pero pienso que puede perderse la calidad de la imagen, y la idea es solo juntar la imagen o foto con el texto y guardarla sin perdida. D: